# Como criar designs profissionais em WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015

Bem, eu não sou Designer isso é fato, e quem não tem habilidades de designer sofre bastante com as novas tecnologias de interface, dentre elas o WPF. Quem não tem um conhecimento de designer vai sofrer para criar interfaces bonitas com o Blend.
Ainda por cima existe o agravante de que materiais de estudo do Blend são bastante escaços.

Eu sou da época das aplicações desktop com as janelas tradicionais e eu poderia usar WPF e criar a interface da minha aplicação com base nas ideias visuais tradicionais do windows form, mas penso que fazer isso é jogar pelo ralo todo o poder de design do WPF e Blend.
Porém, por não ser um designer, não tenho a criatividade necessária para criar algo realmente bonito. O que me resta então?
Buscar inspiração em outras aplicações que fazem uso avançado do WPF.

Eu estou iniciando a criação da janela principal da aplicação, ou seja, a MainWindow, e como inspiração eu estou olhando para a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

São várias técnicas e componentes que foram usados para construir essa janela, então eu estou tentando analisar por partes, para tentar chegar a um visual próximo a esse.
Primeiramente estou buscando resposta para duas características:

1 - Como foi feito para mudar o visual da barra de títulos e como ele conseguiu inserir botões, menu de contexto, campos de texto, etc, nela.

2 - O fundo da janela será uma imagem ou um efeito criado no próprio Blend?

Comment: Eu uso material design nos meus projetos...fica muito bacana e é facil de usar..segue o link: [http://materialdesigninxaml.net/](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/)

Answer (score 3):

Matheus para modificar os componentes você pode criar Styles que alteram as propriedades dos componentes. Sobre o background, provavelmente é uma imagem. Procure por Styling and Templating WPF. Um abraço e boa sorte

Comment: Me parece que o nome do recurso se chama [Window Styles](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WPF-styling-a-Window-in-fcf4e4ce)
Outros links:

[1](http://cloudstore.blogspot.com.br/2008/05/creating-custom-window-style.html)
[2](https://3water.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/metro-style-window-in-wpf/)
[3](http://nf2p.com/how-to/a-basic-borderless-wpf-window-with-bad-drop-shadow/)

Foi sofrido pra achar, agora sei pq muitos ainda preferem Windows Forms para desktop.

WPF ainda é muito obscuro se comparado a windows forms.

Comment: Window Style você altera as propriedades do MainWindow. Para alterar as propriedades dos componentes você pode criar um arquivo xaml com as modificações que você para o componente e atribuir um nome para este estilo e assim fazer o reuso dele. Dê uma olhada neste post http://stackoverflow.com/q/17630968/2588695

Comment: Nesse caso é exatamente isso, mudar detalhes da main window, nesse caso, a barra de títulos. Porém, pelo que andei lendo, não existe uma forma prática de fazer isso.
A barra de título da janela não faz parte do que se chama "area-do-cliente", ela faz parte de uma "area-não-cliente" e para fazer modificações nela é necessário baixar o nível e fazer interop com COM/WIN32.
Para contornar isso o que é feito é esconder a barra de títulos vinda do SO e criar uma nova via WPF. Porém, não se modificou a verdadeira barra de títulos, apenas criou-se uma barra falsa.

Comment: fico grato por você dedicar tempo a essa pergunta, mas realmente decidi "pisar no freio" e ir mais devagar.
Percebi que estuo indo rápido demais para quem não tem experiência nenhuma com WPF. Sendo assim, estou optando por um design mais simples, também baseado em algo que já existe, pois como citei no inicio da pergunta, não sou designer.
Estou agora mesmo criando uma nova pergunta com uma ideia mais simples de design, espero poder contar com sua ajuda lá também.

Comment: Você pode "criar" uma barra de títulos, removendo-a e criando a sua. Você pode remover usando WindowStyle="None", dê uma olhada em https://3water.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/metro-style-window-in-wpf/