# Criar menu lateral igual ao App Clima do Windows 10

Tags: wpf, xaml

Os amigos que me acompanham por aqui, já devem ter lido uma [pergunta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/140441/como-criar-designs-profissionais-em-wpf) que fiz com esse mesmo tema.
Mas como citei em meu ultimo comentário lá, acabei desistindo da ideia inicial, pois concluir que eu estava indo rápido demais para alguém sem experiência em WPF.
Sendo assim, resolvi optar por um design um pouco mais simples, porém igualmente diferente para um sistema que venho trabalhando.
Gostaria de algumas sugestões de quais componentes, layouts, propriedades usar para criar uma `MainWindows` aos moldes do app `Clima` do Windows 10.

Como é necessário começar por algum lugar, primeiramente gostaria de receber sugestões de como criar um menu lateral como aquele, que abre e recolhe ao clicar no botão superior.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quais layouts e componentes devo usar para conseguir isso.

Answer (score 0):

Nos repositórios [GitHub da Microsoft](https://microsoft.github.io) você encontra um específico que possui dezenas de [exemplos de aplicações UWP](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples). Cada um mostrando como usar um recurso específico.

Aqui você pode ver a lista de [Exemplos de Navegação](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples#navigation), talvez aqui tenha o que você precisa, senão precisa garimpar nos outros exemplos.

Comment: Só uma observação. Meu projeto é do tipo WPF Windows Desktop Classico. Não é um Universal App.
Se aplica nesse caso também?

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva Puxa, não. O app de clima é um UWP, por isso não me dei conta que seu não era.

Comment: Recebi algumas sugestões na versão US do stack.
Eu poderia criar um menu lateral comum e definir um tamanho inicial que só apareça os icones. Ao clicar em um botão ou usando MouseOver, defino um novo tamanho para o menu de forma que possa aparecer a descrição.
Para não ficar uma redefinição grosseira, da pra criar um efeito aumentando o tamanho aos poucos, criando assim um efeito de deslizamento.
Isso tudo é teoria, vamos ver na prática :)

Comment: @MatheusSaraiva, no minimo desafiador. Será um trabalho artesanal. Boa sorte. :)